# AndEngine GLES2 Running On Emulator Issue

Tags: android

Is there any way to run AndEngine GLES2 application on android emulator or is it strictly restricted to android devices. Any suggestions will be appreciated, Thanks in  advance.

Comment: check this http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/new-android-emulator-supports-opengl-es2-t7777.html

Comment: But by doing what is mentioned on this link i still get the no GL Congifuation found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i get to know about it. All you have to do is create an emulator with GPU Emulation enabled and then if your pc's graphic card is good enough to support those graphics your emulator will be able to deal with GLES2 applications.

Answer (score 0):

GLES2 uses GPU and emulator does not have support to utilize GPU. So I don't think so it will be possible.